# An experiment is had of 3 independant outcomes: A,B,C who's probabilities of realization are p,q,r respectively.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The whole question:.  An experiment is had of 3 independant outcomes: A,B,C who's probabilities of realization are p,q,r respectively.What is the probability of the series of $A$ length $a $come before a series length of$ b$ series of $B$. I can't seem to put it into coherent workable relations. I know that each monome must have $p^a$ atleast and that series of a's comes last in every individual outcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the probability that $X&lt;Y$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66996/what-is-the-probability-that-xy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\rm\underbrace{AA...AA}_{\text{a times}}$ works $\to$ $p^a$
- $\rm(B\;or\;C).\underbrace{AA...AA}_{\text{a times}}$ works $\to$ $(q+r)p^a=(1-p)p^a$ since $p+q+r=1$
- $\rm(A,B\;or\;C).(B\;or\;C).\underbrace{AA...AA}_{\text{a times}}$ works $\to$ $(p+q+r)(q+r)p^a=1.(q+r)p^a=1.(1-p)p^a$
- we thus keep adding A, B or C until we have added any of those $a-1$ times and stop and then add B or C only beacuse otherwise a A's would be there. Now the process repeats we are now free to add A, B or C another 'a-1' times and then B or C and then ...
- So the sum looks like:
  $$p^a\\+\underbrace{(1-p)p^a+1.(1-p)p^a+1^2.(1-p)p^a+1^3.(1-p)p^a+...+1^{a-1}.(1-p)p^a}\\+\underbrace{(1-p)^2p^a+1.(1-p)^2p^a+1^2.(1-p)^2p^a+1^3.(1-p)^2p^a+...+1^{a-1}(1-p)^2p^a}\\+\underbrace{(1-p)^3p^a+...+1^{a-1}(1-p)^3p^a}+\underbrace{...}+\underbrace{...}+...$$
  that is:
  $$p^a(1+a(1-p)+a(1-p)^2+...)=p^a\left(1+a\frac{(1-p)}{1-(1-p)}\right)=p^{a-1}(p+(1-p)a)$$

Comment: Very well done.